# How to find which button is clicked: jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Summary:** I have a html page which consists of two add buttons and two tables. When add button is clicked, rows are appended to respective table. I have included two templates with two different parent ids into one html template. I need to write the script in such a way that when add-btn having parentid == "#a" is clicked ,append rows to table having parentid =="#a".

result.html

```
//i am using django web framework
<div class="reports">        
    {% include 'template1.html' with id="a" %}
    {% include 'template2.html' with id="b" %}
</div>
```

Each template shares/extends a base.html template where all the common code is written

```
<div class="panel">
    <div>
    <button type="button" class="add btn btn-primary" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Add to configuration list.">
                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                        Add
                    </button>
                </div>

            <div class ="configuration-table panel-body">
                <table class="table table-striped table-bordered table-condensed">
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Remove</th>
                            <th>Layer</th>
                            <th>Display</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>Dataset</th>
                            <th>Ordering</th>
                        </tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
</div>
```

and my jquery code is

result.js

```
    $('.reports').on('click','#a .add, #b .add', function(e) {
//how to differentiate two tables here.
    $(this).find('configuration-table table').children('tbody')
                    .append(
                        '<tr>'+
                        '<td class="remove-row" role="button" aria-label="Remove Region"><i class="fa fa-times" title="Remove this row." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" aria-hidden="true"></i></td>'+
                        '<td>'+layer_text+'</td>'+
                        map_elements+
                        '<td>'+unit_text+'</td>'+
                        '<td>'+dataset_text+'</td>'+
                        '<td class="ordering" aria-label="Re-order"><i class="fa fa-arrows" title="Re-arrange row order." data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right"></i></td>'+
                        '</tr>'
                    );
```

**Issue:** When i click add button, the row is appending to both the tables. and i dont want that. i want to add rows to the respective table. And i want to do that within same function.

I am looking for logic that i am missing here.

Thanks in advance

Comment: A [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) would be great!

Comment: `.on(` is hooked up to what? And you are looking for an element and not a class in the find. NOt sure how that code would work since the table is not a child of the button.

Comment: @epascarello i am looking for logic here. Do avoid pointing out silly mistakes in the code. My request is to understand the concept. anyway i have edited it.

Comment: Silly mistakes make it hard to understand what is going on. Sometimes the "silly" mistakes is why people's code do not work. Remember we are trying to help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is using find which looks for a child of the button. It is not a child, it is a sibling of the parent div of the button.

```
$(this)  //button that was clicked
   .parent() //div around the button
     .sibling(".configuration-table")  //sibling element that has the table
       .find("table tbody")  //the table
         .append(tableRow);
```

Comment: Thank you it helped with little changes.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly as per markup, there is no parent child relation between add button and table. Though, there can be many ways of fixing this issue. Proposing 1 option below

Let us say you have both buttons with class `add` and a data attribute (data-id) containing id of table.

i.e. 1st button having data-id="a" and second button having data-id="b" where a and b are the ids of respective tables.

Now update your js to following

```
.on('click','.add', function(e) {
     var table_id = $(this).data("id");
     $("#"+table_id).children('tbody').append..... // your code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the logic. I'll try using data-id